# How can i attach my content type to level 1 taxonomies in multilevel taxonomy in drupal 7?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

I am using the default taxonomy of Drupal 7. I have a taxonomy like the following one:

- Multilevel taxonomy (Vocabulary)

  - level 1 taxonomy  (Term)

    1. level 2 taxonomy (Term)

I want my blog post have a field type of level 1 taxonomy.

Is there any module for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout [Hierarchical Select](http://drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select) module. It offers many features.

> Hierarchical Select has the ability to save the entire lineage of a
>   selection or only the "deepest" selection. You can configure it to
>   force the user to make a selection as deep as possible in the tree, or
>   allow the user to select an item anywhere in the tree. Levels can be
>   labeled, you can configure limit the number of items that can be
>   selected, configure a title for the dropbox, choose a site-wide
>   animation delay, and so on. You can even create new items and levels
>   through Hierarchical Select!

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply, but it's not what i am looking for.
I want that text-field of term reference type to link with level 2 taxonomy